# Join on Join mysql

Tags: mysql

I am getting an SQL ERROR (1064) Syntax. Is what i am trying to do allowed? As i don't see the syntax error.

```
`SELECT isc_products.prodname, isc_product_variations.* , isc_product_variation_combinations.vcoptionids, 
FROM isc_products 
JOIN isc_product_variations 
ON isc_products.prodvariationid = isc_product_variations.variationid
JOIN isc_product_variation_combinations
ON isc_product_variation_combinations.vcvariationid = isc_product_variations.variationid`
```

Comment: No one. Why do you think it is wrong? PS: don't treat "join on join" as a special case. Join always applied to the constructs precede it. And doesn't matter what it is - `from`, `join` or nested query

Comment: What's not working? Does it return anything at all? What error message do you get? What's your table structure like? Need more info from you!

Comment: SQL Error (1064): SQL Syntax.

Comment: Check over 20 times. Can't spot the problem.

Comment: @jason3w: Did you check the first line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error on the first line. You have a comma that shouldn't be there:

```
SELECT isc_products.prodname,
       isc_product_variations.* ,
       isc_product_variation_combinations.vcoptionids,
--                                                   ^
FROM ...
```

I'd also advise you not to use `SELECT isc_product_variations.*` but instead list the columns you want explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Mark! First week at Learning to program. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You have `isc_product_variations.variationid` twice in your `ON` statements. Check, if this is what you want, or if there is a second key in you perhaps need `isc_product_variations`

Comment: Hey yunzen. Is there a reason i'm not allow to use that common key twice? Still very new at this, so any tips much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: It's not technically that you should look at it, but logically. I don't know, how your tables are structured, so I don't know what you are trying to achieve. If the three tables are built to have a m:n relationship between two of them, your query seems to be false. If you try something different, it maybe right